# WinHttrack User Defined Structure - Relative files in relative folders - Remove query strings

Tags: html, download, mirroring, download-manager

I have two questions.

**Question 1:** 
Is there any way I can download the website based on the following structure using winhttrack?

```
All of the html files go into site_name/
All of the images go into site_name/images
All of the css files go into site_name/css
All of the js files go into site_name/js
```

I tried to use winhttracks different build structures and the one I've found is pretty close to what I need.

```
Html in site_name/ .images/other in site_name/xxx
```

This structure gives me this result

```
All of the html files go into site_name/                 Good
All of the images go into site_name/images               Not Good
All of the css files go into site_name/css               Good
All of the js files go into site_name/js                 Good
```

Just the image section. it saves images based on their extensions also in different folders like

```
All JPGs go to site_name/jpg
```

and so on.

So I've searched and found that I'll have to write user defined structure for this. But Can't find any good guide with some examples explaining it.
Can anybody help me out of this?

**Question 2:**
Winhttrack saves same file with different queries. So style.css saves as

```
style.cssf972
style.css86ff
```

How can I avoid this?